# Show that $(f_n)$ has a convergent subsequence in $C[0,1]$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, approximation

Let $(f_n)$ a sequence of class $C^1$ at $[0,1]$, that is, functions whose first derivative is a continuous function. Suppose for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and for all $0< x\leq 1$ $$|f'_n(x)|\leq  \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\quad\text{and}\quad \int_{0}^{1} f_n(t) \,dt=0$$

Show that $(f_n)$ has a convergent subsequence in $C[0,1]$.

I know that because Bolzano Weierestrass if I find bound for $(f_n)$ then it must has has a convergent subsequence in $C[0,1]$.

Comment: Which concept of convergence do you use on $C([0,1])$? Uniform convergence?

Comment: Bolzano Weierstrass Theorem does not apply to $C[0,1]$.

Comment: What do you mean by $\vert(f'_n)\vert\leq  \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$? That $\vert f'_n(x)\vert\leq  \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$ for all $x \in (0,1]$? Can you update your question to clarify?

Comment: Do you know Ascoli's theorem ?

Comment: Indeed, this is an easy consequence of intergability of $\frac1 {\sqrt x}$ and Arzela -Ascoli Theorem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Mean Value Theorem - MVT, we have for $0 < x \le y \le 1$ and $n \in \mathbb N$

$$\vert f_n(x) - f_n(y) \vert \le \int_x^y \frac{dt}{\sqrt t} \le 2 \vert \sqrt y - \sqrt x \vert \tag{1}.$$

As $x \mapsto \sqrt x$ is uniformly continuous on $[0,1]$, we get that $\{f_n\}$ is uniformly equicontinuous on $[0,1]$.

Moreover the inequalities $(1)$ imply by continuity of $f_n$ that
$$\vert f_n(y) - f_n(0)\vert \le 2$$for $0 \le y \le 1$. Therefore for all $y \in [0,1]$ and $n \in \mathbb N$:

$$f_n(0)- 2 \le f_n(y) \le  f_n(0) + 2.$$

The equalities $\int_{0}^{1} f_n(t) \,dt=0$ have for consequence with the above that the sequence $\{f_n(0)\}$ is bounded by $2$ and finally that the sequence of functions $\{f_n\}$ is uniformly bounded by $4$ (for the $\Vert \cdot \Vert_\infty$ norm).

We get the desired conclusion by applying the [Arzelà–Ascoli theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arzel%C3%A0%E2%80%93Ascoli_theorem).